# Exporting part of windows form as image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mschart

I have a form which shows a graph which was made in Microsoft Chart control 6.0...

I have placed a option in the menubar which will export the graph made to an image file...

Can some one tell how to export the graph part of the form as a image (any format will do)...

I was thinking of taking a screenshot and saving it but i cudnt get the controls in vb to take a screenshot of a specified area on the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's the C# function for it

```
private void capture(Control ctrl, string fileName)
{
    Rectangle bounds = ctrl.Bounds;
    Point pt = ctrl.PointToScreen(bounds.Location);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(pt.X - ctrl.Location.X, pt.Y - ctrl.Location.Y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }

    bitmap.Save(fileName,ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

and call

```
capture(chart1, @"c:\temp.png");
```

Here's the above c# method converted to VB

```
Private Sub capture(ctrl As Control, fileName As String)
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = ctrl.Bounds
    Dim pt As Point = ctrl.PointToScreen(bounds.Location)
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(pt.X - ctrl.Location.X, pt.Y - ctrl.Location.Y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size)
    End Using

    bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

Comment: I am kinda new to stackoverflow so i am still getting used to all this stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

`Imports System.Drawing.Imaging`

```
Public Class Form1  

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)  
    ' Create a graphics object from the bitmap  
    Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)  
    ' Take a screenshot of the entire Form1  
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)  
    ' Save the screenshot  
    bmpScreenshot.Save("D:\Form1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)  
  End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: Oh god, THIS FINALLY WORKS AFTER HOURS OF SEARCHING! <3

Answer (score 0):

The key method to look at is [Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Here's a function that returns an `Bitmap` of a control specified by the function parameter:

```
Private Function GetControlScreenshot(ByVal control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim g As Graphics = control.CreateGraphics()
    Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height)
    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(control.Location, control.Size))

    GetControlScreenshot = bitmap
End Function
```

You can use this function like this:

```
Dim controlImage As Bitmap = GetControlScreenshot(Me.dataGridView)
controlImage.Save("TestImage.bmp")
```

The code's a bit rough but I believe it points you in the right direction.

Comment: your code seemed right cause i was trying to figure out something in the same lines....But when i tried it all it gave me was a rectangle with white color filled inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious, reading visual basic documentations, how to find the linked control between the classes.
I assume the main commands to achieve saving a paintevent with a form are

1. the name for the form control, below, in line five
2. connected to the size property command names
3. the `.CreateGraphics()` command as form `Me.` property

. My next assumption is the creategraphics add an image to
a part of a control logic. To change the appearance of a
,for example, button1 control creategraphics is to consider
the development environment.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
Dim image1 As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Sub Seitenlogik(e As KeyEventArgs)
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Space
                image1.Save("C:\Users\folder_name\OneDrive\Pictures\paper.bmp", _
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                image1.Dispose()
        End Select
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        With Me
            .Scale(new SizeF(1, 1))
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            .Location = New Point(50, 50)
            .CreateGraphics()
            .DrawToBitmap(image1, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))
        End With
    End Sub
    Shared Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
Seitenlogik(e)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Paint
           With e.Graphics
                .DrawString("What do i have to proceed?", New Font("Consolas", 22),
                New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(184, 190, 132, 230)), New Point(50, 50))
            End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above code is tested. The paintevent can be saved. For compiling i used Create a Windows Forms application from the command line,

```html
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-create-a-windows-forms-application-from-the-command-line?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
```